# Creating Dagger 2 component to be shared between src/test and src/androidTest

Tags: android, robolectric, android-espresso, dagger-2

My app uses Dagger 2, Robolectric 3 and Espresso 2 and Mockito.

Robolectric and some unit tests are under src/test/java. Instrumentation tests and some unit tests are under src/androidTest/java.

I am looking for best practices and implementation ideas about adding a Dagger test app component that potentially can be shared between src/test/java and src/androidTest/java. Is this possible? Is it recommended? I use gradle for builds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that for sure and you can create another folder and you can include this folder into two test configuration:

http://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/

Comment: Hi Eugen, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer).

Comment: No issues, glad that Dan already wrote and I just passed it around